# My VBA works on debug mode but not in running mode

Tags: vba

I'm writting a code in VBA to open an internet explorer  website, filling the form with a number and then clicking in the "pesquisar'' button. After that, I need to click on the "partes" button.
My code is working perfectly on debug mode, but when i run it, it doesn't work.
Please help me!

This is my code:

```
numero = Application.InputBox("Por Favor entre com o numero precatorio", "", "")


Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "https://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/numeroProcesso.php?secao=TRF1&enviar=ok"

Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

ie.Document.all("proc").innerText = numero
ie.Document.getElementById("enviar").Click

Set objElementCol = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each objElement In objElementCol
    DoEvents
    If objElement.href = "https://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/processo.php?proc=1219012520174019198&secao=TRF1&pg=1&enviar=Pesquisar#aba-partes" Then
     DoEvents
        objElement.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    DoEvents
Next objElement
```

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit`? What is the value of `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`?

Comment: @braX If he made a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls, the value is 4 (max value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When navigating webpages, I created this routine that you simply call to wait for the webpage to finish loading.

```
Sub ieBusy(ieObj As InternetExplorer)
    With ieObj
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

So in your code, you can use `ieBusy ie`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ieBusy(ieObj As InternetExplorer)
    With ieObj
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
End Sub


Sub test()

    ' Make sure you Declare your variables, such as <numero>
    ' You other code here

    numero = Application.InputBox("Por Favor entre com o numero precatorio", "", "")

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/numeroProcesso.php?secao=TRF1&enviar=ok"

    ieBusy ie

    ie.document.all("proc").innerText = numero
    ie.document.getElementById("enviar").Click

    ' It will become busy again after your click, so make another call
    ieBusy ie

    Set objElementCol = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

    For Each objElement In objElementCol
        DoEvents
        If objElement.href = "https://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/processo.php?proc=1219012520174019198&secao=TRF1&pg=1&enviar=Pesquisar#aba-partes" Then
         DoEvents
            objElement.Click
            Exit For
        End If
        DoEvents
    Next objElement

End Sub
```

> Notice: I added `Option Explicit` to the top of the code. You should get in the habit of *always* adding this to the top of **every** module. This will require you to declare all of your variables.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the problem is hapenning in the "for each" part.

Comment: When I run my program in debug, it works entirely, but when I execute it , it works only until the "for each" part.

Comment: @pedrotedesco Did you make the changes I posted? Did you add BOTH `ieBusy ie` lines I added to your code? Because your problem is after you click `...("enviar").Click`, you were not allowing it to finish loading.

Comment: Your best bet is to start a new question and include the html code in question with it.